# High number of connections in IIS

Tags: web-services, iis

I have hosted our web service on one of the IIS server.
Many of our web service calls are failing for that server. Load on that server seems to be normal despite no of connections.

Below are the statistics

```
Total Reqest/Sec - 150~200
Request Execution Time - 0-10ms (mostly 0)
Request Executing - 0 - 5
PipeLine Instance Count - 0
Web service -> Current connections - 8k~10k
%processor time - 1~2%
```

I do not see major issue here apart from number of connections. How can I reduce the number of connections since web service is mostly returning the static data.

Or is there any other reason that to this?

Comment: Are these .asmx or .svc services?

Answer (score 0):

In the service client, make sure you are closing all the connections that you are making. We had similar issue, and resolved it by just closing the proxy connections on client side.

Comment: we are making calls through C# HttpClient library by Microsoft. How can we close the connections from client side?

Comment: HttpClient client;
   client = new HttpClient("Https:\\ourwebservicepath.svc");
   Uri uri = new Uri("Https:\\ourwebservicepath.svc" + "\ourwebmmethod");
   HttpResponseMessage response = null;
   var credentials = new string[2];
   if (verbs == HTTPVerbs.GET)
   {
       response = client.Get(uri);
   }
   else if (verbs == HTTPVerbs.POST)
   {
      response = client.Post(uri, content);
   }
   return response;

Comment: Can't find the source for the client? Tried this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee391967.aspx, but no code available.

Comment: yes i'm doing same as what is described in the above mentioned link.

Comment: I wanted to see the library. I didn't get the download. There is one option, you can set the service time out on the server for the connections but choose the time out period wisely. Also service type please...svc?

Comment: yes service type is svc. Do we need to set the timeout at IIS level or at firewall level

Comment: This you can do inside the web.config for the service. Check the binding properties closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00".

Comment: Is there any web.config? If yes then you can do it. If no you will need to add it. .Net 4.0 has provision to work without web.config. Please go through [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163394.aspx) article. Also let me know why you are using HTTPClient, is it possible to switch to some other custom code?

Comment: yes I did that half an hour ago but if connection did not decrease

Comment: The time i had given was for example, you can reduce them to may be "00:00:30", 30 secs or even less if your service response time is very less.

Comment: Just to check have you assigned the new behavior to your service. Check [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/360f7997-82f8-40d0-8fd5-8cbbf1c44534).

Comment: Finally got the code for `HttpClient`. Check with `Timeout` property, `.Dispose()` method. Also saw the code, may be there is a bug, if your service Faults, connections are not closing `state.requestStream.Close();` (code from the project). I will suggest you use your own code for this.